# Managing a single apostrophe (single quote) in an JPA Entity column name

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, entity, psql

I have an entity to map a PostgreSQL table which has a column name containing an apostrophe that causes an error

> SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

How do I manage this character?

[Entity and Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txEbv.png)

Comment: The *column name* contains an apostrophe? Egad that's just asking for trouble heh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try delimiting the column name (i.e. surrounding the column name with embedded quotes):

```
@Column(name = "\"CODICE ATTIVITA'\"")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. This way I get a "PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "as" "

Comment: What does the SQL statement look like? You should be able to activate the logging of the generated SQL statements.